# Approximation arguments

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I am a student reading about Luo and Sarnak's paper and I have trouble understanding the conclusion.
In the paper this theorem is proved for a continuous function of compact support $\psi$:
$$\underset{\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}}{\int} \psi(z) d \mu_t(z) \underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{\sim} \frac{6}{\pi} \ln(t) \underset{\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}}{\int} \psi(z) d \mu(z)$$

Then using this fact they assert that for $A$ and $B$ compact Jordan measurable sets we can then prove that
$$\underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{\lim} \frac{\mu_t(A)}{\mu_t(B)} = \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(B)}$$

I do not understand how we obtain this? Why do we need Jordan measurable? I think that if   $\mu$ is a Radon measure using the preceding fact and Urysohn's lemma are we not able to prove it for all measurable sets?

Here is a link to a pdf that I am reading it is not the original paper but it is very similar: http://bb5.pmf.unsa.ba/images/que-notes3.pdf

Comment: That has very little to do with Ergodic Theory, also very little with research. If one wants to use arguments based on weak (star) convergence, one knows about $C_{c}$ functions. If a set is Jordan measurable, for every $\epsilon>0$ its boundary can be covered by a finite union of (regular) sets of total measure less than $\epsilon>0$. For Lebesgue measurable sets, you might have countable union...

Comment: What closed set do you want to apply Urysohn's lemma to if $A$ is, for example, the set of points with rational coordinates? There's no closed sets that will help.

Comment: If $\mu$ is a Radon measure we have for any open set $U$ the following: $\mu(U) = \sup \{ \mu(K) \mid K \text{ compact and } K \subset U \}$ so I was thinking maybee we can apply Urysohn's lemma to $K$ and $U$ to obtain the result for open sets. Then we have that for a measurable set $E$: $\mu(E) = \inf \{ \mu(U) \mid U \text{ open and } E \subset U \}$. This makes me think that the result could be extended to measurable sets but of course there probably is something I am not seeing that makes this argument fail...